# Can we add data to a continuous view in pipelinedb externally

Tags: pipelinedb

I would like to add data to a specific continuous view. I do not want to feed it through the stream as I want to add it only to this specific view with out disturbing others.

I have tried adding rows to the `cv_mrel` table directly but I was unable to as some columns of the view are of **hll**(hyperloglog) type.

Is the any way or a function by which I create/cast to this Data structure from a value?

Answer (score 0):

PipelineDB exposes functions for building and manipulating HLLs:

http://docs.pipelinedb.com/builtin.html#hyperloglog-functions

So in your case I'm guessing you'd want to build representative HLLs and then insert those into the `_mrel` table directly.